# WinForms default Resource file for project

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, resources

We're building an application using WinForms (.NET 3.5)

I am familiar with the concept of *Resources*, however i don't follow the idea of default Resources per project.

In our project i see the usage of resources (RESX files) in the following contexts:

1. Per Project (Set in the project's properties under the Resources tab)
2. Per Control (Form for example) -- our main Form has an accompanying RESX file (expanded under the .cs file in VS)

What is the difference between the 2?

On one hand, having resources per form seems logically correct, but i cannot select Images for example from the specific form resource (only from the global one)

What is wrong here and how should the 2 be used?

Comment: I dont know the idea of having a resource for a particular Form. But what you could do is to have additional resource files under separate namespaces. If you can have a form and a resource file under a namespace, then that sorta forms a clubbing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a resource in more than one form then using a project resource is best.  That way it is stored only once.  If not then keeping it in the form's resource file makes it easier to keep it them organized.

Comment: The designer doesn't let you pick a resource from the Form resources... that's what's strange about it to me. For example when selecting an Image property, it lets you select an image from the project resources, not from the local form resources.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant with "if you want to use a resource more than once".  You can certainly use a form's resource more than once in the same form class but that requires code that uses the ComponentResourceManager class.  The designer doesn't offer the option.

Answer (score 0):

the forms ressources are used for lacalisation , if you configure the form to be localisable, visual studio will create a ressources file for each language :  myform.en-US.resx     myform.fr-FR.resx ....